# Using FINDSTR with quotes and punctuation

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I have a file that contains the following as a JSON key/value pair:

```
"Package": []
```

However, when I try and use the following it does not locate the entirety of the key and the empty array:

```
FINDSTR /L /C:"Package"": []" %dir%
```

How, if at all, can I use FINDSTR to locate the aforementioned JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape quotation marks in `findstr`'s search string, use `\"`:

```vb
findstr /C:"\"Package\": []" "%dir%"
```

Since the number of spaces may vary, I would rather do this:

```vb
findstr /R /C:"\"Package\" *: *\[ *\]" "%dir%"
```

Comment: Thanks! In this instance I was checking for the presence of that empty array so the former snippet worked perfectly for me.